# Как при событии submit проверять какая кнопка нажата

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть форма order_form с 2 кнопками. Нужно отправлять ajax только при нажатии кнопки с id='liq'.

```
$(document).on('submit','#order_form',function(){

        var _data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({  
            url: window.location.href,
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",  
            data: _data,
            success: function(_form){
                $('body').append(_form);
                $("#liqpay").submit();
            }
        });
        return false;

});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Используйте просто событие клик на кнопку с id="liq" и дальше делайте что делали.

```
$(document).on('click','#liq',function(){

        var _data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({  
            url: window.location.href,
            dataType: "html",
            type: "POST",  
            data: _data,
            success: function(_form){
                $('body').append(_form);
                $("#liqpay").submit();
            }
        });
        return false;

});
```

Comment: вопрос был как реализовать внутри конструкции `$("form").submit(function() {…});`, а не `$('#liq').click( function() {…} )`

Answer (score -1):

попробуйте этот рабочий пример кода, в нём ответ на ваш вопрос:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
   var target = null;
    $(':input').focus(function() {
      target = $(this).val();
    }); // не перемащайте этот фрагмент в submit

  $('#order_form').submit( function () {

    if ( target == 'save' ) {
      alert('[Save] is pressed')
    } else if ( target == 'delete' ){
      alert('[Delete] is pressed')
    } else {
      alert('{unknown button is pressed}')
    }
     return false; // это строка заглушка
     // удалите, чтобы данные отправились на сервер
  });
});
</script>

<form id="order_form" action="" method="post">
  <button type="submit" value="save" name="action">Сохранить</button>
  <button type="submit" value="delete" name="action">Удалить</button>
</form>
```

надеюсь вы разберётесь как адаптировать под свой конкретный случай.. думаю, для вас это не будет сложно..